# How to define relations among entities from different datasources?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I'm designing an application that will use data from several databases. I'll use JPA to implement persistence and Spring as main application framework.

I need to handle transactions that will span among different datasources. Googlin' a bit I found that `JtaTransactionManager` could be useful to implement this.

But I'd also like to create relations (at application level) among entities belonging to different datasources. **So that I can work as if the data-layer consists of a single database, without having to worry about the source which the entities "come from".**

Will `JtaTransactionManager` let me do this, or I need some extra component or configuration in Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know no easy existent solution to your problem.

The `JtaTransactionManager` will take care of executing operations with *different databases/datasources* within the *same transaction*, but you won't have the data consistency guaranteed by any databases (like foreign keys between databases).

Besides, `JPA` does not support `@ManyTo*` relationships between different databases (like `EntityFromDb1` has a `OneToOne` relationship tp `EntityFromDb2`), so the solution would be to work with the corresponding Ids. Afterwards it is your task to manage those relationships. Of course with some work from your behalf you could automatize the load of relationships, but there is much more that only that, like cascading, locking, queries joining both databases...

Comment: I do not know what a linked server is (I suppose it is a SQL Server feature). If so, I cannot help you further.

Comment: Yes, it is an SQL Server feature, but it also exists in Oracle DBMS and maybe others... Anyway, thank you very much.